Configuring an antenna for (short distance) ground wave propagation on 40 m?
I'd like to use 40 m for short distance (ground wave) QRP CW.  My criteria for antenna selection is simple:

Works short distance (ground wave)
As simple as possible
As small as possible
Ideally, some degree of portability

What antenna is a good choice for that, and how should it be deployed?
My reading suggests a 40 m dipole.  However, most of the guides I've seen talk about how to deploy it for increased distance (= high angle of radiation).  That seems to be the opposite of my goal.  Is there a smaller antenna I can use? Or a better way to deploy it?

For your goal of ground wave communication, a dipole antenna is a poor choice unless you can erect it at least 20m above the ground. A vertical monopole antenna (about 10.5m long) with elevated radials is the best option, like KC2G commented on the other answer.
I use a tire step-on mount for flagpole with Spiderbeam 12m HD mast (fiberglass) and a wire radiator. You'll need to find the step-on mount with a diameter large enough to hold the mast. Some people built their own step-on mount with plywood. Some people use a hitch mount or bumper/winch mount for the same purpose.
If you are subject to height restrictions, you might want to consider a loaded vertical antenna, but that will reduce the radiation efficiency by 1/10 easily, so I would not recommend it for experimenting with a low-power transmitter. Some people will tell you it will work, but if you want to avoid disappointment, you want to start with something more reliable first.

A dipole is not very portable, nor "small", if by that you mean, small area needed for deployment. A vertical, would be the most space efficient, requiring only one anchor point, 20M or so, off the ground.  This would be an end-fed halfwave antenna, requiring a 49:1 UnUn transformer, with a very short counterpoise. The second most space efficient would be a halfwave, inverted L; this is the same construction as the end-fed halfwave vertical antenna, except after going straight up for as high as you can, your wire goes horizontal for the rest of its length. Obviously, this requires two "sky-hooks", but if you have more horizonal ability than vertical, it is still far better than a ground-mounted 1/4 wave vertical.

It seems easier to me to string a 1/2 wave antenna horizontally than to erect almost anything vertically, especially if it will perform decently when low to the ground.  Since I can roll the dipole up into a coil, put it in my car, and unwrap it where I go, I consider it portable and "small", more than say an erect 1/4 wave.

Certainly a sloping configuration will work, it just changes the radiation pattern.  A center-fed dipole, while easy to build because it doesn't require a transformer, does need three anchoring points, which doesn't make it a first choice if you want a portable, fast and easy antenna to deploy.

That raises a good question: What is the radiation pattern of a center fed dipole on the ground?

@SRobertJames if you really mean groundwave, horizontal antennas have approximately zero groundwave prop. Only vertically-polarized signals travel in groundwave. (On the other hand, a low horizontal dipole can do NVIS).
